contravariant finiteness and limit closure: is there dual to a result of Crawley-Boevey?
Let $\mathcal A$ be a locally finitely presented category. Theorem 4.2 of https://doi.org/10.1080/00927879408824927 says that given a full additive subcategory $\mathcal D$ of finitely presented objects $fp(\mathcal A)$, the category consisting of direct limits (i.e. colimit) of objects from $\mathcal D$ is closed under products if and only if $\mathcal D$ is covariantly finite in $fp(\mathcal A)$ (i.e., every object of $fp(\mathcal A)$ admits a left $\mathcal D$ approximation).
I want to ask: Is there a dual to the above criteria? Namely, is $\mathcal D$ being contravariantly finite in $fp(\mathcal A)$ (i.e., every object of $fp(\mathcal A)$ admits a right $\mathcal D$ approximation) related to any property of the subcategory of $\mathcal A$ consisting of objects that are limit of objects from $\mathcal D$ ?
